# How can I perform a live-update on my function? JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

(I have recreated it somewhat in the JSFiddle, keep in mind that it doesn't have any aesthetic visuals, its just basic to show and the `<script>` is also down below in the HTML code)

I have written [this small function](https://jsfiddle.net/ZanicL3/s3yot1ym/2/) from bare bone, the basic behind it is that it should recreate a form (by adding classes in HTML from a function), which gives 4 correct check marks (the green ones) in the right corner, **when they are all filled in**, and 4 fault check marks (red marks) when they are **not all filled in or none of them at all when the user hits send.**

But now for example when a user fills in 3 of them but not one not, it will show an red check mark on all of them, how can I make it look like it only will show a redmark on the one that is not filled it, and even if he fills in the one that was not filled it it will not 'update' only when the user refreshes the page, how can I fix that?

Also how can I give a live update for example, when the user types in for example their name and moves on to the next text field which will be the subject then it should already show a greenmark for the name one, how can I fix that?

Thanks for all the effort and help in advance. (I know this form will never work since I need PHP for this.)

Comment: Use the `onblur` event to detect when a field has lost focus so you can check it - jQuery: `$('input[type=text]').on('blur', function() { code; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this . See the below Snippet

```js
jQuery('.notchecked').on('input', function() {
  nietLeeg($(this));
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
  var reEmail = /^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$/;

  if (!sEmail.match(reEmail)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}


function nietLeeg(elem) {

  if (elem == null) {
    var elem = $('.notchecked');
  }

  elem.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() && $this.attr('id') != 'email') {
      $this.removeClass('nochecked').addClass('checked');
    } else if ($this.attr('id') == 'email' && validateEmail($this.val())) {
      $this.removeClass('nochecked').addClass('checked');
    } else {
      $this.removeClass('checked').addClass('nochecked');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.contactmiddle>input[type="text"] {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.contactright>input[type="text"] {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.checked {
  background-image: url("http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/check-mark-31.png");
  background-size: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
.nochecked {
  background-image: url("http://www.falconpedia.de/images/6/63/No_check.png");
  background-size: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="contactmiddle">
  <input class="notchecked" id="naam" name="contactpersoon" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text">
  <input class="notchecked" id="email" name="contactpersoon" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text">
  <input class="notchecked" id="subject" name="contactpersoon" placeholder="Subject" required="" type="text">
</section>
<section class="contactright">
  <input class="notchecked" id="bericht" name="contactpersoon" placeholder="Message" required="" type="text">
  <input class="knop" onclick="nietLeeg();" type="button" value="send">&nbsp;
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect!

Comment: Any idea how I can make it only give a green check mark when there is a _@_ and _.com_ in the email field?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the follow Jquery/JS code :

```
function nietLeeg () {
       var inputs = $('input');
        inputs.each(function(){
      var presentInput = $(this);
      if(presentInput.val() == ''){
      presentInput.removeClass('checked');
      presentInput.addClass('nochecked');
      }
      else{
      presentInput.addClass('checked');
      presentInput.removeClass('nochecked');
      }
      });

    };


  $('input').on('blur',function(){
  nietLeeg();
  })
```

On every `blue` event the function will be called. 
The function works in the following way :
if the `input` field is empty -> it will remove the `checked` class and add `nochecked` class. and vice versa for a non empty `input` field.